# Play Services are outdated

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to register my app in GCM. `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` returns error code `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`. I call `getErrorDialog()`. User goes to the market, but user has last version of Play Services. Same on the other phone. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem by changing line in build.grade of module to the `com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+`.
You may use higher version, just make sure that user will have high enough version in the Play Store.